# Fail of multicoring host in SimGrid

Tags: simgrid

There is a multicoring host declared in `platform.xml`

```
<host id="Host" speed="1Gf" core="280" state_file="Failures/Failure/h_0" >
```

When I rum simulation SimGrid gives me:

```
[0.000000] /simgrid-master/src/simix/smx_environment.cpp:43: [xbt/CRITICAL] Error while loading /home/Platform/platform.xml: FIXME: add state change code also for constraint_core[i]
```

How to set state failures properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you ask for (applying trace to a multicore host) is not implemented yet, hence the "FIXME" is the error message, which should be a "TODO" or more explicit about the "UNIMPLEMENTED" character of this feature.

Comment: Do you know will it be implemented soon?